# How to change [[ ! $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] to word options in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have an input in my script that writes to a file needed to run some software, however the software only allows for one of 2 possible options, namely LO and LDO.

The input I already have written is at the top of the following code, and the code at the bottom is the code that was suggested that I want to manipulate

I would like to have the question "Overlap (LO or LDO): " and an error message if one of those options arent entered and to repeat that step, instead of going through the whole script again, rather than searching for values between 0 and 9

**from what i can gather, I need to change the ^[0-9] to include LO and LDO, but I am not sure what punctuation or how to do it**

```
### My Script ###
read -p "Overlap (LO or LDO): " OVERLAP

### Recommended Script ###
#!bin/bash
number=""
while [[ ! $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do
    echo Please enter your age
    read number
done
echo You are $number years old
```

Answer (score 2):

An input-and-validate loop is often written like this:

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Overlap (LO or LDO): ' overlap

    case $overlap in
        LO|LDO) # ok
            break
            ;;
        *) # not ok
            echo 'Please enter LO or LDO' >&2
    esac
done
```

I.e., you have an infinite loop that you break out of when you have validated the answer as correct.

Obviously, you could also do that as

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Overlap (LO or LDO): ' overlap

    if [ "$overlap" = LO ] || [ "$overlap" = LDO ]; then
        # ok
        break
    fi
    # not ok
    echo 'Please enter LO or LDO' >&2
done
```

Or, with a shell that has `select`:

```
echo 'Select overlap:' >&2
select overlap in LO LDO; do
    case $REPLY in
        [12]) # ok
            break
            ;;
        *) # not ok
            echo 'Please select LO or LDO' >&2
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&&` and operator:

```
#! /bin/bash
overlap=""
first=1
while [[ $overlap != LO && $overlap != LDO ]] ; do
    if [[ ! $first ]] ; then
        echo 'Wrong answer, please answer LO or LDO!' >&2
    fi
    read -p 'Overlap (LO or LDO): ' overlap
    unset first
done
```

You can also use a regex:

```
until [[ $overlap =~ ^LD?O$ ]] ; do
    ...
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `?` makes the previous thing optional
- `$` matches the end of the string

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot. How could i go about writing an error message in that, where if LO or LDO isn't given, then an error message shows asking to repeat? sorry if im asking too much

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate all of this

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
while read -p "Overlap (LO or LDO): " overlap;
do
 [[ "$overlap" =~ ^LD?O$ ]] && break || echo "Not LO or LDO"
done
```